# Question about SR latch timing

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, flipflop, latch, timing

I have a question about how SR latches work:

[image]

To my understanding the real-world implication is that one of the two gates will receive power first and produce an output signal, and they aren't going to turn on at exactly the same time.

For simplicity assume top gate is "gate R" and bottom gate is "gate S."

Is it conceivable that both gates are powered up before the signal from one gate reaches the other?

Say gate R receives power, interprets 00, outputs a 1, but before that signal reaches gate S, it also powers up, interprets 00, outputs a 1.

And so both gates would be outputting 1 briefly until gate R's 1 output finally reaches gate S and causes it to output a 0.

Meanwhile gate S's original output of 1 is heading back to gate R and causes it to change from outputting a 1 to outputting a 0 as well, etc etc etc?

I'm struggling to understand how it all fits together, the timing implications, and where the delays are and how they're enforced and what can happen vs. what can't happen, etc.

Comment: If the distance between a gate output and the other gate input was 0.5 inch, then the signal will propagate in about 80 picoseconds for most flavours of PCB material (and a bit faster in wire) so the uncertainty window is not very wide.

Comment: @PeterSmith Are you saying "the signal is very very fast even at long distances"? What do you mean by uncertainty window not being wide? Meaning that one will power up and propagate its signal well before the other one powers on?

Answer (score 1):

The time it takes for the power supply voltage to rise is much, much longer than the propagation delay of the gate outputs. So, both gates are more or less in the process of powering up at the same time. Their behavior during this period of time is undefined and generally unpredictable. If the inputs to the latch are for the HOLD condition (00 in your case) then the initial state of the latch is unpredictable. Having said that, if you build one latch circuit that particular circuit might wake up the same way every time but that doesn't mean that the next latch you build will behave similarly.

Comment: What makes the initial state unpredictable? What does it depend on -- which gate powers up first (even if it's just a smidge sooner than the other)? If we maintained the 00 input state would the gates keep switching back and forth between 00 and 11 as in the example?

Comment: Why should the initial state be predictable? If you stand a pencil on its point it will fall one way or another. A given pencil might be unbalanced in a way that makes its fall predictable, but in general you cannot predict the direction that a pencil will fall. Random variations in transistor parameters will cause the latch to eventually prefer one state or the other but in general the initial state of a latch at power-up cannot be predicted.

Comment: I get that part, but I am asking what does this unpredictability depend on exactly? Is it strictly whichever of the two gates powers on first?

Comment: The unpredictability depends on every aspect of a real manufactured circuit. The transistors are a little different. The wire resistance and capacitance is different for different paths. My point is that talking about "which one powers on first" just doesn't make sense...the supply voltage rises very slowly compared to the timescale of gate behavior.